# How to stop Simple from writing `class` attributes to XML files?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

I'm using [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to read and write 3rd party XML files. Reading works great, but when writing collections the library puts extra `class` attributes in the resulting file, like this:

```
<translation class="java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap">
    <!-- stuff here-->
</translation>
```

My schema doesn't allow for these, I'd like to have plain tags with just the attributes I explicitly put there, like these:

```
<translation>
    <!-- stuff here-->
</translation>
```

How can I tell Simple to stop writing these and just guess what collection it should use, like it usually does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually [mentioned on project's page](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#intercept), you have to use a Visitor. It's quite simple:

```
public class ClassAttributeRemoverVisitor implements Visitor {
    @Override
    public void read(Type type, NodeMap<InputNode> node) throws Exception {
        // Do nothing, framework will guess appropriate class on its own
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Type type, NodeMap<OutputNode> node) throws Exception {
        OutputNode element = node.getNode();
        element.getAttributes().remove("class");
    }
}
```

To use this visitor, you have to add a VisitorStrategy to Persister's constructor:

```
new Persister(new VisitorStrategy(new ClassAttributeRemoverVisitor()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simple workaround:

```
@Path("translation")
@ElementMap(inline=true)
Map translation;
```